# How many CP do "Traits" cost in 2E Skills & Powers?

Tags: adnd-2e, optional-rules

I'm trying to roll a character using the [*Players Option: Skills & Powers*](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/16863/Players-Option--Skills--Power-2e) book, and I'd like to add some traits to my character.  Chapter 6 (Nonweapon Proficiencies) has a section called "Acquiring Character Traits", which says:

> Character points must be spent at the time of character creation if players want to select traits.

However, the Traits table (table 46) only lists the trait names and initial rating — *not* cost!

[image: Screenshot of Table 46: Traits showing an “Initial Rating” column but no cost]

The Trait Descriptions section also doesn't give costs, but again hints that each trait does have a cost, e.g.:

> Halflings can purchase this trait for 1 less character point than the listed amount.

But again, it's not listed anywhere I can see, or am I blind?

TL;DR: How many CP should I be spending for each trait I want to add to my new character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table 46 should have its second column labeled "Cost" instead.  [This and various other errata for the somewhat infamously poorly edited Skills & Powers book can still be found on wizards.com](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/DnDPlayersOptionSkillsPowers2ndErrata.asp), but who knows for how long.

If you're using the Player's Option series a lot, back in the day I wrote an integrated, classless, fixed version of the whole mess (S&P, C&T, S&M) that we playtested a lot and [is still online at my old Web site](http://www.mindspring.com/~ernestm/classless/).

Answer (score 4):

Table 45 (Nonweapon Proficiency Groups) has four columns: **Proficiency**, **Cost**, **Initial Rating**, and **Ability.**  (Ability scores modify a Non-Weapon proficiency. Modifiers based on Ability Score are found in Table 44).

Example:

```
    Trait       Cost  Initial Rating            Ability  
 Deep Diving     2        5                Dexterity/Balance, Constitution/Health.
```

Table 46 (Traits) has two columns: [**Trait** and **Cost**](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/DnDPlayersOptionSkillsPowers2ndErrata.asp)
Example:

```
Trait       Cost  
Alertness     6
```

Traits are described as something that can modify a proficiency roll, so it makes little sense to me that the second column would be the "Initial rating" for a Trait.

> Traits often benefit characters' use of proficiencies, improving their chances for success. (From the introductory paragraph to table 46 "Effects of Traits")

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the values indicated in the Initial Rating column as the cost.  (See my earlier comment regarding the legitimacy of my copy.)